# Codeigniter form_validation callback function issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback, codeigniter-3

my code is as follow:

```
class Test_model extends MY_Model
{
  public $validation_rules = [
    'field' => 'input_text',
    'label' => 'Your Text',
    'rules' => 'trim|callback_checkString',
    'errors' => [
      'checkString' => 'Invalid String',
    ]
  ];

  public function checkString($x){
    return $x==='valid';
  }

  /* callback function */
  public function do_my_job(){
    /*form_validation is already loaded in autoload.php*/
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->validation_rules);
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
      /*do something*/
    }else show_404();
  }
}
```

when I call $this->Test_model->do_my_job() all other validation works but callback function not works....
it always throws my custom error 'Invalid String' !!!...

any solution?...

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an error message for your custom rule. In your case adding the message to `$validation_rules` would be very easy.

```
public $validation_rules = [
  'field' => 'input_text',
  'label' => 'Your Text',
  'rules' => 'trim|callback_checkString',
  'errors' => ['checkString' => '{field} text is not valid'],
];
```

The other option is to use the `set_message` method right after `set_rules`.

```
$this->form_validation
     ->set_rules($this->validation_rules)
     ->set_message('checkString', '{field} text is not valid');
```

[Setting Error Messages Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-error-messages)

This next bit doesn't answer your question, but please consider this variation on `checkString`.

```
public function checkString($x)
{
  return $x==='valid'; //this will evaluate to a boolean, if/else not required
}
```

**Part 2**

The problem of a valid input not being validated is because of where the callback function is defined. Form_validation expects the validation method to be in the controller. (Technically, it actually looks for the method in the `CI` "super object" and that object IS the controller.) Moving the callback definition to the controller should cure all.

**Part 3**

If you want to make a custom validator available to your whole website and to keep your code DRY the easiest way to do that is to extend `CI_Form_validation`. Easier to do than you might think.

Create the file `application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`
Here's the code

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
  public function __construct($rules = array())
  {
    parent :: __construct($rules);
  }

  //Add any custom validation methods.

  public function checkString($x)
  {
    return $x === 'valid'; 
  }
}
```

DONE!

You load form validation exactly the same as always and you use your new method the same way you use the rules included with CI. You do not use the `callback_` prefix.

Here's how your new rule would now be setup in your model.

```
public $validation_rules = [
  'field' => 'input_text',
  'label' => 'Your Text',
  'rules' => 'trim|checkString',
  'errors' => [
    'checkString' => 'Invalid String',
  ]
];
```

The `do_my_job()` method is unchanged.

Comment: thanks :) according to your suggestion I've set an error msg for the 'checkString' => 'invalid String' & now the prevoius error is solved, but the custom msg 'Invalid String' is thrown even though I input 'valid' through input field! :'(

Comment: even i tried:  public function checkString($x){ return true; }

Comment: OK, figured it out. Should have remembered this issue. See Part 2 of the edited answer.

Comment: ok sir, but is there any way so that I can write the callback function in Model class?

Comment: Not that I know of. When `form_validation` finally gets to actually locating the callback it looks first in the controller instance. It also looks in itself - `$this`. So, if you want to make the function available throughout the application extending the `form_validation` is the way to go. Want me to edit the answer and demonstrate how to do that? Or you can read about that [topic here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#extending-native-libraries).

Comment: I went ahead and edited the answer to show how to extend form validation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140012/discussion-between-amin-and-dfriend).